# Initialize Selenium Page Objects, Best Practices

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I have been asked to create an application that will fill out and submit forms to a third party website using Java, Selenium and PhantomJS (I am an intern, so all of this is pretty new to me).

This will require bouncing around about a dozen different pages. I am using the Page Object model with a different class for each page. My question is:

What is the best way to initialize all of the page objects?

I am currently doing it this way. I initialize several pages during setup:

```
public class MyProject
{
    private HomepagePageObject homepagePageObject;
    private SecondpagePageObject secondpagePageObject;
    private ThirdpagePageObject thirdpagePageObject;
    private FourthpagePageObject fourthpagePageObject;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public MyProject()
    {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.homepage.com");
        homepagePageObject = new HomepagePageObject(driver);
        homepagePageObject.clickButtonForSecondPage();
        secondpagePageObject = new SecondpagePageObject(driver);
        secondpagePageObject.clickButtonForThirdPage();
        thirdpagePageObject = new ThirdpagePageObject(driver);
    }
 }
```

Some pages cannot be accessed during setup (i.e. a page that confirms a submission). So everytime I come across a page that may or may not have been initialized, I do this:

```
    if(fourthpagePageObject == null)
    fourthpagePageObject = new FourthpagePageObject(driver);
```

This seems like a messy way to do this. Is there a 'best practices' for initializing page objects when you do not know what order in which the pages will be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using a factory class, something like this:

```
class PagesFactory{
    private WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage getHomePage(){
         return new HomePage( driver );
    }

    // if you want to share the same object (singleton) among many tests

    private SecondPage secondPage;
    public SecondPage getSecondPage(){
         if( secondPage == null ){
              secondPage = new SecondPage( driver );
         }
         return secondPage( driver );
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

In our project we are using Spring to instatiate WebDriver and inject it into many factory classes (we have a dozen or so factories, each one groups pages of different parts of our application). 
In test classes we simple get needed factories, and all test methods simply refer to a factory object when some page is needed.
In Java it could be done for example in the below way (but we also use Spring to instatiate and inject factories to our test classes):

```
class TestSomePartOfApplication{
    KKKPages kkkPages = KKKPages.getInstance();
    AtosPages atosPages = AtosPages.getInstance();
    .....
    void testScenario1(){
       kkkPages.getPageA.fillField("Field name 1", 120 );
       kkkPages.getPageA.clickButtonOK();
       ......
    }

    void testScenario2(){
       kkkPages.getPageB.fillField("Field 15", "abc" );
       kkkPages.getPageA.clickButtonOK();
       atosPages.getPageC.fillField("Field 33", "Client name");
       ......
    }
}
```

---

Since you wrote in the question

> Some pages cannot be accessed during setup (i.e. a page that confirms
>   a submission). So everytime I come across a page that may or may not
>   have been initialized, I do this:

so I guess that you are using a navigation strategy in which the page object is responsible for creating a new page object of another page if some operation nawigates to this new page. This is a common advice found everywhere, You can find examples of this strategy in many articles related to the Page Object Pattern, usually a classic example of a login page:

```
class LoginPage{

    public HomePage loginUaer( String user, String password ){
        // fill in fields and click Login button
        .....
        .....
        return new HomePage( .... );
    }
}
```

But we found that this strategy is very difficult to folow in a complex application with a lot of pages which are composed of many common elements, but differ from each other only in minor details. This approach increases a complexity of the project, because many classes must be coupled with each other, also a page object in many cases must be statefull, andd must remember previous operations performed on the page, or must use some other methods (checking a page/window content?) to decide if a navigation can or cannot be done, and which kind of navigation (for example - when user enters a wrong password, then one error message page is displayed, if he leaves fields empty then another page is shown, otherwise if username and password are OK, then he is forwardet to the home page, etc. etc.). To to this, some complex rules must be implemented in the page object, that mimic a behaviour of the application - this is very laborious and error prone.
We are using another strategy instead, described here:
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html

> Having page objects be responsible for creating other page objects in
>   response to things like navigation is common advice. However some
>   practitioners prefer that page objects return some generic browser
>   context, and **the tests control which page objects to build on top of
>   that context based on the flow of the test (particularly conditional
>   flows).** Their preference is based on the fact that the test script
>   knows what pages are expected next and this knowledge doesn't need to
>   be duplicated in the page objects themselves. They increase their
>   preference when using statically typed languages which usually reveal
>   page navigations in type signatures.

This approach works very well for us. We have a lot of independent, decoupled and stateless classes (POJOs) that implement very simple operations on the pages - or even only on some part (section) of the page. Imagine a case where there are hundreds of pages that share a common elements (like a customer list, a client data section, an attachment section, a messages section etc. etc.), and they are differ only slightly from each other (one page has section A,B,C, the other one has B,C,D etc.). It would be not practical to create a separate page object for each page (hundreds of clases - it's a nightmare). We have only a few independent page objects for each such a section, and a navigation flow is implemented in the test itself, something like:

```
pageFactoryA.getSectionAPage().clickButtonB();
pageFactoryB.getSectionBPage.fillInCustomerField( customerName );
pageFactoryA.getSectionCPage.clickButton("Display customer report");
// the above operation should display a new page: Customer Report
// so we get a CustomerReportPage from the factory
int total = pageFactoryC.getCustomerReportPage().getTotal();
assertEquals( total, 2000 );
.....
```

Comment: It will take me a while to absorb all of this, but very detailed answer. Thank you very much.